# How to fix error 'FB' is not defined no-undef on create-react-app project?

Tags: facebook, reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I made the project using this link as my starting file.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

But after i tried to make Facebook login button with follow by their official docs with this.

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log('login mount');
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '320866754951228',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.6'
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            //this.statusChangeCallback(response);
        });

    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
```

So i got this errors when the browser was refreshed.

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/components/user_profile/LoginForm.js

/Sites/full_stack_production/xxxxx
  70:13  error  'FB' is not defined  no-undef
  76:13  error  'FB' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

So i guess because ESLint that cause this errors.
How can i fix this or make the exception for this `FB` variable?

Thanks!

Comment: As FB is a global and create-react-app is modules, you might have to shim this. Is the application working even with the error?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331165/how-to-workaround-fb-is-not-defined

Answer (score 46, accepted):

ESLint doesn't know that the variable `FB` is a global. You can declare a variable you referenced as a global by adding the following to the top of your file:

`/*global FB*/`

For more information, check out the "Rule Details" section on the official ESLint docs: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef

Answer (score 16):

If you use Create React App, you need to explicitly grab global variables from `window`.
For example:

```
// It's a global so need to read it from window
const FB = window.FB;
```

However, if the library is available as an npm package, you can use imports:

```
// It's an npm package so you can import it
import $ from 'jquery';
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: window.FB is also undefind for me ? i'm only getting access to it inside  window.fbAsyncInit = function () { console.log(window.FB) } this works but outside its undefined ?? what to do

Answer (score 13):

Based on what @dan-abramov stated in a comment to another answer:

> Don't use `FB`, use `window.FB`

This way, you define explicitely where the variable FB needs to come from.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your .eslintrc file, so you only have to define it once and not in every single file:

```
"globals": {
    "FB": true
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I can fix this by use `this.FB` instead just `FB`

Comment: Don't use `this.FB`, it is quite confusing. You want `window.FB`.