# can't compile react app with forge viewer - can't compile - Autodesk not defined un-def

Tags: autodesk-forge

we want to move some of our forge viewer code base into a react-app and can't figure out how to use the viewer3d js api without appending all Autodesk.Viewer.... usages in our components with window.* This works in all the (excellent and extensive) git samples we've studied. why? we load the viewer3d.js file in the index.html between the  and the react landing :

```
<body>
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=6.0" />
  <div id="root" />
```

the error we get (for every instance of usage of the Autodesk namespace):

```
Failed to compile

./src/components/Viewer.js
  Line **:  'Autodesk' is not defined  no-undef
```

this works:

```
this.viewer = new window.Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(this.viewerContainer)
```

this doesn't work:

```
this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(this.viewerContainer)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in this [user guide](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/0febe269b555d922f7726f30d505ed5cca2598ec/docusaurus/docs/using-global-variables.md), you need to explicitly read any global variables from window. Put this at the top of the file and it will work:

```
const Autodesk = window.Autodesk;
```

And it's recommended to yank your script tag to the header section of your app's entry html to make sure it gets loaded prior to the React emits:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  ...
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=6.0" />
  </head>
...
```

Comment: Sorry just dug out some doc re this - didn't run into this myself but I was using TypeScript which might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

we resolved this by putting a global in the first row of our component files.
based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40467882/2337681).

```
/*global Autodesk*/
```

but, i do like this one even better, right behind the imports. thank you, Bryan.

```
const Autodesk = window.Autodesk;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a [autodesk-forge-viewer](https://github.com/mazhuravlev/autodesk-forge-viewer) typing module, you can use it to verify types during compilation.

It is used this way:

```
import Autodesk from 'autodesk-forge-viewer';
const autodesk: typeof Autodesk = (window as any).Autodesk;
```

For some limitations of type latest TypeScript the type will be **Autodesk** and the value will be **autodesk**, so here is the code to create a Viewer instance:

```
const viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D = new autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerContainer);
```

Please take a note that *autodesk-forge-viewer* module doesn't include Viewer implementation, so you still must add viewer3D.js script to the index.html.