# Forge configurator inventor add custom extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

How can I add custom extension into autodesk [forge configurator inventor](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor).
For example I want to add [transform](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/tree/master/public/extensions/TransformationExtension) or [model transformer](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Viewing.Extension.ModelTransformer) extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are **Viewer** extensions, so you will have to load them into the **Viewer**.

In that sample the web part using the **Viewer** seems to be here:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/WebApplication/ClientApp/src/components/forgeView.js

So this is where you would have to add a reference to the given **JavaScript** library file and load the extension from it using viewer.**loadExtension**()

More info on extensions here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/extensions/

Comment: I know the viewer is working there yes. I write the load function into it and run it, and for example I am trying to add the import necessary for transform and register it. But I get an error because it doesn't see Autodesk and Three, however autodesk is defined in forgeView.js. Errors like this "   'AutodeskNamespace' is not defined  ,
    'THREE' is not defined  "

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165163/cant-compile-react-app-with-forge-viewer-cant-compile-autodesk-not-defined

Comment: This should help https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-viewer-extensions-design-automation-inventor-sample

Comment: Now I've seen it Adam.I will try it tomorrow at the earliest opportunity.Michal also shared your post, thank you. There is no place where you share the codes in full. is not it? I'm following you on github, but I guess it's not there :)

Comment: OK. I added the full source code of transformtool.js to the blog post

Comment: Now I tried it and it worked. Thank you. Again, I will try to install the other extension with this logic.I'll look at the full code again